# I'm looking for theoretical materials about the design and history of bilingual books

Tags: typography, page-layout, design-principles, resource-recommendations, book

I plan to make a bilingual book (Polish/English, Polish/Russian) for my thesis, so I'm looking for theoretical materials (books, articles, textbooks), where it is written about the design and layout features of bilingual books, what are the page design options in such books, oh how to stack text in different languages in one book, and other questions, features and problems in the design of such books. I'm also looking for materials about the history of bilingual books.

Thank you in advance for any information!

Comment: Welcome! Questions should really show *some* effort on your part and not merely be "google search" input - Google exists for such cursory questions. What have you found thus far? Why are your finding insufficient? Are you seeking books related *general design*  as well as issues such as bilingual layouts, or merely books related to bilingual layouts? Do yo have any experience with design or will this be your first foray into such a project? It is one thing to be a designer and need a nudge for a specific project, it's another matter to never have designed anything and start from  zero.

Comment: Think of it this way... you want to build a car from the ground up. Before you even start, you need to understand how the internal combustion engine functions so the car you build will at least meet the technical requirements for its engine. So you need to have some understanding of book *design* before you even venture into any bilingual layout.

Comment: If Google had helped me in the search, I wouldn't have asked this question. I know about book design and am studying to be a graphic designer, but bilingual books are rare and it is very difficult to find information specifically about them (not just on forums, but in reliable sources (books, articles, etc.).
In the design books that I read, and from lectures at the university, I did not find information about bilingual books (what are the features of their perception? what is the best way to make such a book so that it is convenient for the reader to read?).

Comment: Hi @avgustgrustny .. it may be helpful if that last comment was part of the question itself. You can [edit](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/162644/edit) to clarify. My initial comments were  far more exploratory - and *not* judgmental in any way. There's really no way of discerning from the question, as it stands, if this is anything more than a "Google it for me" question.

Comment: @avgustgrustniy you be suprised how often that is not true. Anyway i dont think you can have an answer that basically answers with all art on the field. You should probably scope the question down so it does not sound like a literature study for a masters thesis.

Comment: If you are looking for examples, look for books from places with multiple official languages (think Canada (English/French), Belgium (French/Flemish), etc....) Most of what you'll find will be things like technical/instruction manuals, museum catalogues, event programmes and the like